# CSRF - Gracefully Fail Stale Sessions

Tags: php, ajax, session

We built a SaaS platform that allows users to create a message and share it across any advertising medium via an pre-determined alphanumeric code.

All of our forms use a CSRF token, but I noticed a problem. If a user is editing their message, then takes a break, and comes back to finish editing and hits save, they are faced with a 'CSRF mismatch' warning message. This is a critical problem, as they have to refresh the page, losing their changes, in order to regenerate a valid token.

What's happening is that the initial CSRF token is generated based on static params such as filename and php_uname(), but it is also being generated via session_id(). So if the session_id changes, a new CSRF token is generated and obviously does not match the old token resulting in the warning message.

It would be easy enough to disable CSRF protection on forms that require user authentication, but we have a few forms that do not require authentication, such as user login. Granted it's not a big deal to show the 'CSRF mismatch' on a user login, but it does look wonky to users who have no idea what that means, and end up going 'screw this' and leaving the site.

So I am looking for an alternative solution, to maintain some semblance of form protection, without generating a worthless warning message.

Two potential solutions...

1) Instead of generating a CSRF based off session_id, generate it based off some cookie value, this will allow graceful cross session handling.

2) Drop CSRF altogether. Instead, validate the REFERER of all form posts, and if they match the parent domain, then proceed. This will ensure other sites are not posting to our forms (the primary purpose of CSRF). We actually use this solution for our ajax requests.

We are leaning towards option #2 but wanted to check to see if there were any other graceful solutions to consider.

Comment: Don't use REFERER, it is trivial to spoof and can not be trusted.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Good point, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with option #1 (Cookie solution), and treat the CSRF seeding just like a persistent login cookie. If the seed isn't available in current session, check cookie, if exists, populate current session. Seems to be working well and transcends stale sessions.